# How to add the sum from multiple values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total sum for property listings for multiple cities. The code below works for only 1 city but I need it to add the sum for more than just 1 city.

This is for MYSQL php output on website.

```
SELECT sum(case when p.city = 'Denver' then 1 else 0 end) ''
FROM __property AS p
LEFT JOIN __property_propmid as pm on pm.prop_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN __property_categories AS c on c.id = pm.cat_id
WHERE p.stype =1 AND p.state =1 AND c.id IN (4)
```

The code works for the total sum for one city. I need to add multiple cities and have the sum as the result. For example Denver, Colorado Springs, Boulder, etc. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `COUNT` instead and `WHERE city IN(Denver, Colorado Springs, Boulder)` maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you should need to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` to get count of what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM __property AS p
LEFT JOIN __property_propmid as pm on pm.prop_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN __property_categories AS c on c.id = pm.cat_id
WHERE p.stype =1 
   AND p.state =1 
   AND c.id IN (4) 
   AND p.city IN ('Denver', 'Colorado', 'Springs', 'Boulder')
GROUP BY p.city
```